# Cat weight guide for Russian Blue

Tags: cats, health, weight, age

I have recently bought a Russian blue kitten. According to the breeder, she is 3 months old (well, 3 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> now). Last week, when i brought her to the vet for a check, the vet was baffled. She said that she does not know the breed well, but the cat seems to be way too small and weights too little to be 3 months. My kitten weights 700g (1.5 lbs). Looking for weight guides for other breeds seems to indicate that my cat indeed is not 3 months yet, or maybe just extremely small.

Does anyone here have a Russian blue and knows how much a 3 months old kitten should weight?

I mean, it doesn't really change anything at all, since i'm free feeding her, it's more out of curiosity.

Thanks :)

Comment: how many kittens did the mother cat get,large litters tend to grow slower than small litters will do.can you be sure about the age of the kitten? how much weight do your kitten gain in one week?https://www.askthecatdoctor.com/kitten-weight-chart.html

Comment: to estimate the age of your russian blue kitten you can look at the eye color,at four months old the kitten wil have a green ring around the pupils a kitten younger than this will have yellow eyes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I measure the weight of my cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21976/how-can-i-measure-the-weight-of-my-cat)

Comment: this Q&A is related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28280/is-my-kitten-going-to-grow-up-to-be-massive russian blue is a medium sized breed so the weight chart should be fine for your kittens weight.

Answer (score 2):

OP here. This is going to be an answer to the comments. I've posted as a guest (haven't made an account yet). As a guest, i can't answer to the comments directly.

Back to topic:
Thanks for the answers.
To my knowledge, the mother cat had 3 kittens. I can't be sure about the age of the kitten. I only have the date that was written in the sanitary book/Passport of the kitten. She gained roughly 60grams this week (i think that's 2.1oz?)

I can't see any green ring around the pupils yet. Also, by going with the weight chart, the kitten would seem to be indeed only around 8 weeks old, and not 12.
Which surprises me, because she needed to get a vaccination against rabies by law, which in turn again, is only allowed to be made once the kitten is 3 months old.

Comment: 60 grams of weight gain is fine in a week,remember you can accept your own answer and get some more reputation :)

Comment: Seems i can add a comment now becuase i'm in the same session still.
Happy to hear the weight gain is fine. I guess i'm just surprised that she seems to be 8 weeks old, and not 12 weeks old like she is supposed to be.

Comment: it is a bit suprising why the breeder lied about the age of your kitten  but as long as the kitten is healthy she should be fine,it might be that the breeder wants to get the mother cat into heat again sooner to maximise profit but it is hard to tell if this is the reason and it is not good for the mother cat to be treated this way.

Comment: It is pretty weird. Especially because this would mean the vet was in on it aswell, since she was required to get the rabies vaccine, which isn't allowed before 3 months.
Also, there wasn't an ad online to sell the kitten. I just contacted the breeder directly. I'd assume she'd have had an ad somewhere, if she wanted to sell her asap.

Comment: Please merge your accounts - mods can do this.